# Custom total/discount is being calculated after tax instead of before

Tags: magento2, custom, tax, discount

A client of us wants to give logged in customers a discount based on the full order amount of the cart. The discount amount is saved in a custom attribute as percentage. The discount is working as expected, but the resulting tax Calculation isn't. The tax is calculated without taking the discount into calculation.

Hopefully anyone is able to shed some light why this is happening and if there is a way to add a discount to the order before TAX is being calculated.

Tax amount is 21% (The Netherlands).
Current Magento 2 version is 2.3.2.
There are no other modules that are related to this as far as I know.

Here is a screenshot of what it is happening right now:
[image: calculation summary]

Text version:

```
Subtotal: 400
Discount: -40
Shipping: 35
tax: 91.35 ((400 + 35) * 0.21)
Total inc. tax: 486.35 (tax + 395)
Total exc. tax: 395,- (400 - 40 + 35)
```

This is what it should do:

```
Subtotal: 400
Discount: -40
Shipping: 35
Tax: 82.95 ((400 + 35 - 40) * 0.21)
Total inc. tax: 477.95 (tax + 395)
Total exc. tax: 395,- (400 - 40 + 35)
```

The tax amount should be calculated based on the amount with the discount deducted (but shipping included), but the tax amount is based on the full amount. The settings have been set to "Apply Customer Tax after discount" so this is set to the correct value (see screenshot). This value isn't overwritten in another view either. It looks like Magento is just ignoring the custom discount completely when calculating the tax amount. 
[image]

Code has been mostly taken from: https://github.com/magepal/stackexchange/tree/develop/104112/TestDiscount and modified.
`app/code/Vendor/DiscountOnOrders/etc/sales.xml`

```
<section name="quote">
    <group name="totals">
        <item name="DISCOUNT_ORDER" instance="Vendor\DiscountOnOrders\Model\Total\Quote\Custom" sort_order="500"/>
    </group>
</section>
</config>
```

`app/code/Vendor/DiscountOnOrders/Model/Total/Quote/Custom.php`

```
namespace Vendor\DiscountOnOrders\Model\Total\Quote;

use Magento\Framework\Pricing\PriceCurrencyInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Api\Data\ShippingAssignmentInterface;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total;
use Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total\AbstractTotal;
use Vendor\BackOfficeIntegration\Helpers\UserHelper;

/**
 * Class Custom
 * @package Vendor\DiscountOnOrders\Model\Total\Quote
 */
class Custom extends AbstractTotal
{
    const DISCOUNT_PAYMENT_IN_ADVANCE = 'DISCOUNT_PAYMENT_IN_ADVANCE';
    const DISCOUNT_ORDER = 'DISCOUNT_ORDER';

    /**
     * @var PriceCurrencyInterface
     */
    protected $priceCurrency;

    /** @var UserHelper */
    protected $userHelper;

    /**
     * Custom constructor.
     *
     * @param PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency
     * @param UserHelper             $userHelper
     */
    public function __construct(
        PriceCurrencyInterface $priceCurrency,
        UserHelper $userHelper
    ) {
        $this->priceCurrency = $priceCurrency;
        $this->userHelper = $userHelper;
    }
    /**
     * @param Quote $quote
     * @param ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment
     * @param Total $total
     * @return $this|bool
     */
    public function collect(
        Quote $quote,
        ShippingAssignmentInterface $shippingAssignment,
        Total $total
    ) {
        parent::collect($quote, $shippingAssignment, $total);

        $customer = $this->userHelper->getCustomer();

        // First check for the 'order_discount_percentage' attribute
        $orderDiscountPercentage = ((float)$customer->getData('order_discount_percentage'));

        if ($orderDiscountPercentage) {
            $label = __('Orderkorting');
            $discountAmount = -($quote->getSubtotal()/100)*$orderDiscountPercentage;

            $appliedCartDiscount = 0;

            if ($total->getDiscountDescription()) {
                // If a discount exists in cart and another discount is applied, the add both discounts.
                $appliedCartDiscount = $total->getDiscountAmount();
                $discountAmount      = $total->getDiscountAmount()+$discountAmount;
                $label               = $total->getDiscountDescription() . ', ' . $label;
            }

            $total->setDiscountDescription($label);
            $total->setDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
            $total->setBaseDiscountAmount($discountAmount);
            $total->setSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getSubtotal() + $discountAmount);
            $total->setBaseSubtotalWithDiscount($total->getBaseSubtotal() + $discountAmount);

            if (isset($appliedCartDiscount)) {
                $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
                $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount - $appliedCartDiscount);
            } else {
                $total->addTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
                $total->addBaseTotalAmount($this->getCode(), $discountAmount);
            }
        }

        return $this;
    }

    /**
     * Add discount total information to address
     *
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote
     * @param \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total
     * @return array|null
     */
    public function fetch(\Magento\Quote\Model\Quote $quote, \Magento\Quote\Model\Quote\Address\Total $total)
    {
        $result = null;
        $amount = $total->getDiscountAmount();

        // ONLY return 1 discount. Need to append existing
        //see app/code/Magento/Quote/Model/Quote/Address.php

        if ($amount != 0) {
            $description = $total->getDiscountDescription();
            $result      = [
                'code'  => $this->getCode(),
                'title' => strlen($description) ? __('Orderkorting (%1)', $description) : __('Orderkorting'),
                'value' => $amount
            ];
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

Thanks everyone! :)

Comment: Hi, do you have any solution for this problem ?